# How to specify a config-ref dynamically?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Is there a way in mule to specify a configuration reference dynamically?

instead of having:

```
<a:connector config-ref="the_config_name" other-properties="here" />
```

Something like the following?

```
<a:connector config-ref="#[flowVars.configName]" other-properties="here" />
```

This is needed because the configuration used has some properties (URL) that does not allow dynamic values since they are instantiated at the start of the mule app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, config-refs are static. Instead, configurations themselves can be dynamic in Mule 4. This requires special handling of the parameters so that then can be re instantiated per configuration.
For more information on this, you can take a look [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/static-dynamic-configs).